# How to separate a group of genres I'm scraping and updated to a nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping a site and I'm collecting the genres for each book. For example I'm getting "Action, Drama, Romance" into a string a now i want to separate each genre to add it to a collection so the book can be in the action list or romance list and so on.

I'm collecting the genre with the code below and it will output "Action, Drama, Romance". I also have a list of Genres that i want to populate with the ones I'm scraping. The code below works but it gets added as `["action", "Romance"]` together. Is there a way to separate this and add each genre separately?

```
genre_scrape = doc.css('div#content .borderClass .js-scrollfix-bottom div:contains("Genres")').text.split(' ')[1..-1]

genre = Genre.where(title: genre_scrape).first_or_create
book.update(genres: [genre] )
```

Book model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

Genre model

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the code below.

```
genre_scrape = doc.css('div:contains("Genres")').text.split(' ')[1..-1]
genre_text = genre_scrape.blank? ? "" : genre_scrape
genre = []    
genre_text.each do |g|
 genres = g.gsub(/\,/,"")
  genre << Genre.where(title: genres).first_or_create do |genre|
   genre
  end
end
anime.update(genres: genre)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you have more than one genre in `genre` and if so run a loop that adds every genre to the book.